# Import module does not work through terminal, while it works through IDE

Tags: python, windows, import

I have a projects consisting of two packages like this:

```
MyProjectDir
-Package1
--__init__.py
--file1_1.py
--file1_2.py
--file1_3.py
-Package2
--__init__.py
--file2_1.py
--file2_2.py
--file2_3.py
```

Now, in the packages the files have some imports between files:

**file2_3.py:**

```
from Package2.file2_1 import *
run_some_code()
```

When I run file2_3.py directly from PyCharm, everything runs ok. But when I try to run the script in the terminal (I'm working on Windows 7):

```
D:\SVN Repo\MyProjectDir\Package2> python file2_3.py
```

or alternatively

```
D:\SVN Repo\MyProjectDir> python ./Package2/file2_3.py
```

It seems python can't see my packages and I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Package2/file2_3.py", line 1, in <module>
    from Package2.file2_1 import *
ImportError: No module named 'Package2'
```

What is the reason?

**EDIT: If in the import line I use `from file2_1.py import *` without the package name, the IDE underlines the import as "Unresolved Reference Package2" (though it can run), and the terminal works...**

Comment: Can you do a 'which python' in pycharm terminal and the same in windows terminal? also check in pycharm terminal 'import sys' and 'sys.path' and the same in windows terminal to check if there are any differences

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that the way in which you are running the program *is wrong*, PyCharm is aware on how to handle python submodules and thus executes the file correctly.

If you have a package `package1` with a module `package1.my_module` you should run this using the `-m` switch:

```
python -m package1.my_module
```

Do **not** run it directly:

```
python package1/my_module.py   <-- NO! Incorrect
```

Also: you should run the file from *outside* the package.  So if your project is:

```
MyProject
  |
  +- package1
  |   |
  |   +- file1.py
  |
  +- package2
      |
      +- file2.py
```

Your working directory should be `MyProject`.

My personal advice: **never** run submodules directly. Instead put the code in a *separate* script that is outside the package. So I'd have:

```
MyProject
  |
  +- package1
  |   |
  |   +- file1.py
  |
  +- package2
  |   |
  |   +- file2.py
  |
  +- scripts
      |
      +- script1.py
```

Where `script1.py` imports the modules it needs:

```
from package1 import file1
from package2 import file2

# code
```

Then you can run that script from your `MyProject` directory:

```
python scripts/script1.py
```

When you want to deploy your code you'll write a `setup.py` scripts that adds `package1` and `package2` as packages while `script1.py` as a script and they will be installed in the correct directories so that you'll be able to import `package1` and `package2` from everywhere and run `script1.py` from everywhere.

Comment: yay, it worked. 
thanks for this comprehensive answer, appreciated!